# TeamViewer 12 & Ubuntu 16 - Can't Connect

Tags: teamviewer

4 hours in and I am ready to kill someone.
I have installed TeamViewer 12 on a remote Ubuntu server. Everything has installed fine and appears to be running, except that TeamViewer cannot connect out to TVHQ, so no TVID can be issued.

I have opened up (with ufw) ports 5938 (and in desperation ports 80 and 443 as well).

I believe the issue is that teamviewer is listening only on localhost:

```
netstat -ntap | grep teamviewer
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8172/teamviewerd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5939          127.0.0.1:37164         ESTABLISHED 8172/teamviewerd
```

no amount of killing and restarting the daemon (as suggested in other posts) has helped.

I can't find any place to configure this and it shouldn't really be necessary.

What else to try?

Answer (score 1):

an easy fix for me is
Same problem after Upgrading to Ubuntu 17.04 Beta, but i was tired of playing around with network DNS connections hoping it would fix itself in the final version.

and, this worked for me after 2 weeks of giving up. 
It won't survive a reboot though, but it is a temporary fix.

sudo teamviewer daemon stop

sudo teamviewer daemon start

I hope this helps, Mark
Ubuntu 17.10 Beta with Gnome

Here is my previous post for fixing the DNS issue in 17.04
dddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

Here is my (a) solution for general network (DNS, Server, Connections, Loading, Teamviewer ...)  issues which solved the Teamviewer "Not Connecting".

I realized that this issue was originating from a service called ‘systemd-resolved’. This is a DNS caching and validating service that comes pre-installed with Ubuntu 17.04

The solution came from this website

https://www.hecticgeek.com/2017/04/ubuntu-17-04-systemd-dns-issues/.service NetworkManager status

Go to the Update section half way down